# Arabic word Searching from Arabic text File

Tags: android, regex, string, search, arabic

I am working on a Quran application. I have text file(`UTF-8`) of the Quran (in Arabic language). I want to search my Arabic word from the Quran. I want to write an Arabic word of Quran without Aarabs e.g. Zaber, Zair, shud, Mud and Paish.
Aarabs are basically Arabic vowels.
[Arabic Aarabs detail](http://www.as-sidq.org/durusulQuran/articles/vowels-2.htm)

Following is the code to search the English word from my `ArrayList` called `testingarray`. But for Arabic it's not returning the correct word.

```
testingarray.get(Index).toString().trim().toLowerCase().contains(word.trim().toLowerCase())) {
```

Comment: hi @Tarikhelian how did you create Quran interface in android? I mean continuous textboxes that each part of texet can be clicked!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the [Arabic set table of the Unicode](http://unicode-table.com/en/sections/arabic/), It's more easy to use Regex to filter such complex text.

This is an example for short vowels removing in PHP (I'm not a java programmer)

```
text.preg_replace("/[\x{064B}-\x{065F}]/u","")
```

There are more other vowels in Noble Quran you may need to add their ranges.

Just to be more accurate you may need to [Normalize the Arabic text](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/).